# can i change Ibook html widget behaviour

Tags: ibooks, ibook-author

i am creating an "iBook Author html widget", That perform some calculation(a simple calculator), Everything work perfectly but my problem is that i want to show widget on page rather then "Default.png" image, and my widget should not be open in popup and workable in place where it is placed.

Is there any setting in plist which can change behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into the same problem when building our first book. iBooks Author doesn't support inline HTML widgets, unfortunately. If you want inline behavior, you have to use one of the existing widgets (video, slideshow, etc.).

You can customize the `Default.png` file (documentation [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5068)) but that's about it.